# Application got shut down in WinXP if I close the 2nd window of that application

Tags: windows, windows-xp, crash, shutdown

I'm using WinXP and here is my question:
I run an application, such as Chrome, there would be one app in the task bar, and it's fine. Suppose a new window of Chrome opened(so there would be 2 window and 2 in the task bar), and when I close that,the 2nd one, the whole application just shutdown.

And so does chrome, firefox, evernote, Becky!(the email client), even TortoiseSVN. So I think there should be a generic problem cause these applications shutdown, such as the platform - WinXP.

Please give me some advice or hint, anything comes to your mind would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP is grouping the windows in a single one when you close one it closes the entire group, you can prevent this behavior easily, instructions here http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/ht/gptkbtip.htm

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I　didn't close that entire group, and I've disabled taskbar button grouping function. I just CTRL+W in the 2nd window of that application, and the whole application would shutdown.